# Code deleted but still outputting

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have removed several functions from my Codebehind .aspx.cs page. However the webpages are still calling the functions even though I do not call them nor to the functions actually exist anymore.

The code is working exactly like it did prior to removal...I have no idea what is going on.

Things I have tried:

- Navigated to the pages using different computers and browsers.
- Restarted IIS Services
- Restarted IIS Application Pool for Website
- Searched entire project for code that is being called
- Cleaning ASP.NET Cache using following code:

---

```
public void ClearApplicationCache()
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    // retrieve application Cache enumerator
    System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

    // copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }

    // delete every key from cache
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
    }
}
```

**Environment**

- ASP.NET 2.0
- IIS 6
- Windows Server 2003
- XP / 7 to browse (Chrome/IE)

Is the code cached somewhere?? I am rendered clueless.

Comment: Here's a clue: this is ASP.NET, not ASP Classic.

Answer (score 1):

In order for changes to take effect you must recompile your code and redeploy. Looks like you did not replace the DLLs.

You can read more about it here:

[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - See Compilation part.

Comment: This seems out of my depth. I have the project open in visual studio, but no option to 'compile'? Assuming as this is a Website not a web app?

Comment: When I say compile I mean `Build` the project. The resulting product (DLLs) of this is generally placed in the bin folder. These are the files you must copy and paste on the server.

Comment: Thanks @Leniel Macaferi I will try a build and inform you of the outcome.